# Unbind the dynamically created edit button

Tags: jquery, events, button, dynamic, unbind

I've a dynamic button to edit some data for an object.
Now, once the data is updated successfully, I'm throwing an alert to the user, stating that it was successfully done.

However, when the user edits the same object 2nd time, it throws the same alert twice. Likewise, thrice when the same object is updated for the 3rd time and so on.

I believe, I need to unbind the click event on the dynamic button to fix this and ensure that alert pops-up only once each time the object is edited.
How do I unbind the click event on '.edit-btn' button in my code below?
Here's the code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit-btn', function(){
    var objIndex = $(this).parents('.parent').index();
    $('#updateForm').submit(function(e){
        updataData(objIndex);
        return false;
    })
});

function updateData(oldObjIndex){
    // I've the code here to grab the new values from the form

    /* Assign the new values to the new object */
    var newObj = {

        "key1" : value1,
        "key2" : value1,
        "key3" : value1,
        "key4" : value1,

    }
    savedData.splice(oldObjIndex, 1, newObj);
    alert('Updated successfully!');
}
```

Comment: Try something like `$(document).off( "click",".edit-btn)"` from this source http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Move the `submit()` handler outside of the `click` handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to put `submit()` handler outside `click()` like below and check:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var objIndex = '';
    $(document).on('click', '.edit-btn', function(){
       var objIndex = $(this).parents('.parent').index();
    });

    $('#updateForm').submit(function(e){
        updataData(objIndex);
        return false;
    })
});
function updateData(oldObjIndex){

    var newObj = {
        "key1" : value1,
        "key2" : value1,
        "key3" : value1,
        "key4" : value1,
    }
    savedData.splice(oldObjIndex, 1, newObj);
    alert('Updated successfully!');
}
```

Comment: If I do that, I can't pass the objIndex to the updateData method correctly. It doesn't work.

Comment: @Sunny  check now and try

Comment: perfect! Thanks a ton! That's what I was exactly looking for! :)

Comment: @Sunny  glad to help you :):)

Comment: Hi, I'd asked another question which is about the problem I'm facing after fixing this. Could you please help me fix it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43846292/unable-to-update-the-object-after-unbinding-dynamic-button-click